# Eclipse why is there weird text when you look at the tab for an image?

Tags: eclipse, file, icons, png

I've been following a tutorial series on Youtube for learning to program games with java and Eclipse.  At one point, I had to drag and drop a PNG file into a folder and when it finished, the guy in the video had a document icon and when he opened the tab for the image, there was just text with letters and symbols but, I got a globe icon and when I opened the tab for the image, I saw the image.

why would there be a difference and what does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are just using a different editor for image files. The default editor in current Eclipse releases is the internal web browser which will show you the image. Older releases didn't use this editor and just tried to show you the contents of the file as though they were text.

You can see the same result by right clicking on the file and selecting 'Open With > Text Editor'. This isn't very useful as trying to change a binary image file with the text editor will damage the image.

Comment: You can use the Preferences 'General > Editors > File Associations' to change the editor for a file extension. But the editor you are getting is the best one. The text editor is dangerous because you can damage the image.